# Use of preposition "from" after "across"

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I need a little help with these sentences:

> The cafe is across *from* the tailor.
>   The cafe is across the tailor.

Which one is correct? Thank you!

Comment: Because _across from_ is largely replaceable by _opposite_, it is considered a (multi-word) preposition by many. People accepting this wouldn't call 'from' a separate preposition in this structure (though they don't agree on what to call 'across from' – University of Illinois opt for 'phrasal preposition' but 'compound preposition' and 'complex preposition' are also used. I stick with M-W preposition.)

Answer (score 1):

Someone may have a sash across his chest. "across from" is short for "The café is across the street when you come from the tailor's/ seen from the tailor's shop".

Answer (score 1):

Of the two options given, the more accepted would be "The café is across from the tailor."

However, ultimately, it may be preferred that one would be more specific, such as, "The café is across the street from the tailor."

Answer (score 0):

> The cafe is across the tailor.

This is dead wrong.

Comment: On the other hand you can say "The cafe is across the street."